# if condition skips a count

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement, timer

I have tried numerous conditions that I couldn't remember now. 
[image] 
Results are :

- 0:59:58 then 1:00:00 ~ it skips 59th sec
- 0:60:01

  ```
  Private Sub stopwatch_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles stopwatch.Tick
  lock()
  ts.Text = ts.Text + 1
  If ts.Text < 9 Then
      ts.Text = "0" & ts.Text
  ElseIf ts.Text = 60 Then
      If tm.Text < 9 Then
          ts.Text = "00"
          tm.Text = "0" & tm.Text + 1
      Else
          ts.Text = "00"
          tm.Text = tm.Text + 1
      End If
  ElseIf tm.Text = 59 And ts.Text = 59 Then ' this is where I am having trouble with
      If th.Text < 9 Then
          ts.Text = "00"
          tm.Text = "00"
          th.Text = "0" & th.Text + 1
      Else
          th.Text = th.Text + 1
      End If
  End If
  End Sub
  ```

  How can I make it count to 59s? Because after 58, it resets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to make it work, thank you for the insights.

```
If ts.Text < 10 Then
        ts.Text = "0" & ts.Text
    End If
    If ts.Text = 60 Then
        If tm.Text < 9 Then
            ts.Text = "00"
            tm.Text = "0" & tm.Text + 1
        Else
            ts.Text = "00"
            tm.Text = tm.Text + 1
        End If
    End If
    If tm.Text = 60 And ts.Text = "00" Then
        If th.Text < 10 Then
            ts.Text = "00"
            tm.Text = "00"
            th.Text = "0" & th.Text + 1
        Else
            ts.Text = "00"
            tm.Text = "00"
            th.Text = th.Text + 1
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
ElseIf tm.Text = 59 And ts.Text = 59 Then
```

to

```
ElseIf tm.Text = 60 And ts.Text = 60 Then
```

It may seem counter-intuitive, but when you perform you math before the loop, you are not reaching 59, but only 58.

You can simplify your code significantly by changing it to this:

```
' Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
Dim ts As TimeSpan = stopwatch.Elapsed

th.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", ts.Hours)
tm.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", ts.Minutes)
ts.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", ts.Seconds)
```

Comment: you both have the same answer, so I have the same comment. maybe you have other way around?